# Combine "delete query"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making a stored procedure but the query doesn't work.

```
create proc deleteUser

    @username varchar(50)

    as
    begin
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'delete from lars.userInformation where username='+@username;
    'delete from lars.userAcces where username='+@username
    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql,N'
    @username
    ',@username
    end
```

How could I do this without using joins?

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL?  It doesn't seem to be necessary here.  And why can't you use a join?

Comment: Not only is it unnecessary, it is dangerous because of SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why is it dangerous for sql injections?

Comment: What if `@username` was `xyzzy'; drop table lars.userAcces --`?

Comment: @tosorro: Imagine if I call `deleteUser ''''';drop table lars.userAcces'`

Comment: Oke, I understand but how could you prevent sql injection, when you're using dynamic sql?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need dynamic sql:

```
create proc deleteUser
    @username varchar(50)

as
begin
    delete from lars.userInformation where username=@username;
    delete from lars.userAcces where username=@username;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use the EXEC statement. Can you not just perform the DELETE statements directly, preferably using a TRANSACTION?

Answer (score 1):

The optimum solution is to add a constraint to the table so when the parent record is deleted, child records are automatically deleted.

This will ensure the data has integrity no matter how the parent row is deleted.

Example:

```
-- foreign key constraint
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OrderDetail]  WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_OrderDetail_Order] FOREIGN KEY([OrderID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Order] ([OrderID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
```